# When I have to use verb with "to" and when without?

Tags: verbs

"I want to discuss this with you" or "I want discuss this with you". I'm not specific about this sentence. I catches myself saying often for example "I want o write you a letter" instead of "I want write you a letter" and so on and feel, it my be not correct. Background: I'm a German native speaker, perhaps there is somethings specific in German, which I try to translate into English? You see it, in the last sentence I use "try to translate"

Comment: You should say "Want to" and "Try to translate"

Comment: If you can't proofread your own question title and question body for typos then it comes across as unappealing to answer. Why bother, if you aren't going to bother

Comment: @GoDucks Now it is ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Some verbs that are followed by the to-infinitive:

I **decided to** go home as soon as possible.
We all **wanted to** have more English classes.

***Common verbs followed by the to-infinitive are:***

*Verbs of thinking and feeling:*

```
choose
decide
expect
forget
hate
hope
intend
learn
like
love
mean
plan
prefer
remember
would like
would love
```

**Verbs of saying:**

```
agree
promise
refuse
```

***Other common verbs are:***

```
arrange
attempt
fail
help
manage
tend
try
want
```

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/ar/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive[enter link description here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/ar/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive)

Comment: If you copied this answer from somewhere else, please cite your sources appropriately. For more information, see [How to reference material written by others](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Thank you.

Comment: It is not necessary to give lists of verbs with to-infinitive as the to-infinitive is the normal thing. You have to know the dozen verbs where you use the bare infinitive. And you have to know the verbs with gerund instead of to-infinitive.